# Open Compute Server needs 220v to run. Can I use voltage convertor to run it?

Tags: electrical, power-backup

So I bought an open compute kind of server  and it runs on 220 volts and 700 watts power supply. So I decided to purchase a voltage converter(Transformer)  My question is is this stable and will I have problems in the future? Please excuse me I am kinda new to this thing.

I also forgot to mention that I hooked up a UPS which gives 865 watts between the power source and the converter which is connected to my server.

Until now, I am afraid to turn it on, I am afraid of fire. So please I need your help Thank you

[This is the transformer I bought](http://www.ebay.com/itm/151101894787?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

[this is the server](http://www.ebay.com/itm/391293435900?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT)

Comment: Where do you live? What is the model number of the transformer?

Comment: I live in Pittsburgh Pennsylvania which the voltage is 110

Comment: Have you checked to see if the power supply is 120/240 switchable?  If not, can't you just replace the server power supply with a 120v unit? I can't imagine that would be more expensive than buying a transformer.

Comment: i already bought a transformer, and I don't know where to find a power supply for that, I mean can I buy a power supply that is 700 watts the same as the server's power supply and add to the server? Will it function as intended?

Comment: @longneck I edited the question with links

Comment: Looks like a standard server power supply to me.  Those run around $20 for a solid used one and should be really straight-forward to replace.

Comment: Okay I will look into it and return the transformer

Comment: You might want to look at the labeling on the power supply. It might be dual voltage. Must mainstream power supplies are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, you have easy access to 240 volts. Look up a tutorial on how to add a circuit for a dryer or an electric stove.

Comment: I don't know man but it sounds interesting but I will just go for the power supply one since it is easier for me to grasp on.

Answer (score 1):

You have already purchased the transformer and it is rated 300W above your load you should have no problem running off the transformer in step up mode 110 to 220.
I would look at your computer closely as many supplies these days are rated for universal voltage ~100 to 230 volt range. Some have switches 110/220 if you have a switched supply on 110 and connect to 220 it will let the magic smoke out.
I did this on a system at work built it in my office with 110 then hooked it up in the system (it was 220 fed) and forgot to move the switch oops.

Comment: lol so you forgot to switch the input selector accordingly at the transformer side. I will keep an eye on that. The thing is that I read a lot of reviews about these transformers which let me to believe that someday while I am not home something will go wrong with the transformer and burn the house down

Comment: I used them at Hewlett Packard here in the US when working on systems that were only 220v going overseas. I never had one fail but did blow a fuse a few times when I overloaded them.

Comment: Yeah man they are very unreliable and dangerous if not careful. I will just go for the power supply and save myself a headache.

Comment: First off, transformers aren't dangerous if you know how to work with them. Second, and as mentioned in the answer above by longneck, in a US system the voltage comes off of the powerlines into a transformer. This utility transformer converts the high voltage down to 240V. We simply split the circuit with a neutral to get 120V. It's so counterproductive to transform this back up to 240V when you already have it in your panel. It might require an electrician to install the outlet, but it's the best answer. - a second transformer like you have will rocket up your power bill as well.

Comment: I agree transformers are not dangerous.Transforming from 110 to 220 will not change your power bill. Power in the primary is approximately equal to the power in the secondary.
There are only very minor losses in transforming up or down. Having an electrician put in a 220 line would cost over 500 plus permits and that is if it is an easy location to get to.

Comment: So it is better for me to get a power supply right?

Comment: I have used step up transformers for years and never had a problem. My 1 problem was with a 110-220 power supply that I set to 110 to format and configure then forgot to turn the power supply back to 220 plugged it in to a 220 feed and all the magic smoke came out.

Comment: okay what about the ups will it function as intended if used with the transformer?

Comment: some UPS's output are not true sine wave so it would depend on the model. The best way to find out would be to plug it in and unplug the ups. A good one should be fine but a less expensive may not like the inductive load and shut down

Comment: I exaggerated a bit to stress the point that I don't think it's worth it to buy the transformer and run the inefficient route. Sure power is roughly equal on both sides, though I was referring to how the transformer itself will draw power. Running a voltage that you already have seems easiest, but it all comes down to where that line is going.